# Can anyone help the functionality in jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

when selected the button the two siblings of select button should be disabled and after clicking 1st it should be displayed continue button respectively

Comment: insert your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bprakash23/zf2ambLw/5/

can you check here please @sergey kuznetsov

Comment: you want your "Continue with 6 months plan" button to become active after clicking on the higher "Select" button?

Comment: yes, if i select whatever select button the continue button should be displayed on bottom and other two select buttons should be fadeout, even if i select 2nd and 3rd it would be same functionality and also if i select the continue text buttons sholud be one is 3 months and other is 1 months to be populated.

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov i have given image in description, please check and do needful.

Much appreciated in advance!!

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov Can you help me out about the text if selected for 3 months
 "continue with 3 months" and rest same and about disabled buttons also.

Comment: Have you checked my answer with buttons? It is a little unclear now what exactly do you want? Can you give a detailed description of what else you want in addition?

Comment: I got expected answer thanks a lot just one more functionality you missed
i.e if i click on active select button and the other two should be disabled, can you help me with that and please check the image i posted in the description..@sergey kuznetsov

Comment: Of course I can

Comment: And when I click on the "Continue with 6 months plan" button, then all the "Select" buttons should become active, and the "Continue with 6 months plan" button itself should disappear?

Comment: i updated your code here please check and i just need to disable once if i select any button the two select buttons should be disabled please check here..
Note: Normally the active one will be displayed but if i go with select button with 3 months or 1 months the rest 'select' buttons should be disabled.
https://jsfiddle.net/bprakash23/zf2ambLw/21/

Comment: I ran the code. Check please. Was it necessary?

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov Thanks a lot much appreciated and thanks for your valuable time,i got it. Great Work sir!!

just need one doubt for future reference, if i don't want to disable select button but i just want to fade out and somehow user mind changes he want to go with first plan without disability how do i approach?

Comment: I am very glad to help you, but even with the translator I cannot understand what you wrote above :(

Comment: if my answer helped you, please tick it to the left of my answer. and try to ask your question again and I will try to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Was such a result necessary?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.btn-select').on('click', function(){
  $('.btn-continue').css('display', 'none');
  $('.btn-select').prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).parents('.monthly_plan').find('.btn-continue').css('display', 'block');
  $(this).prop('disabled', false);
 });
 
 $('.btn-continue').on('click', function(){
  $('.btn-select').prop('disabled', false);
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
 });
 
});
```

```css
.card.first_mnth-details{
    padding: 1rem;
    border-top: 10px solid #E3D6B4;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #00000029;
    text-align: center;
}
.card.first_mnth-details .price{
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.monthly_plan{
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.container{
  padding:40px 0;
}
.btn-continue{
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
  background: #e78471;
}
.active{
  display:block;
}
.btn-select{
  background: #fffbf0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="monthly_plan">
                    <div class="card first_mnth-details">
                        <p class="price">₹999 per month</p>
                        <p>Order Now & Save 63%</p>
                        <p class="home-del">*Home delivered and billed monthly for the next 6 months</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-select"> Select</button>
                    </div>
                     <div class="pt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-continue btn-block">Continue with 6 months plan
                         </button>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="monthly_plan">
                    <div class="card first_mnth-details">
                        <p class="price">₹1499 per month</p>
                        <p>Order Now & Save 44%</p>
                        <p class="home-del">*Home delivered and billed monthly for the next 3 months</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-select"> Select</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-continue btn-block">Continue with 6 months plan
                         </button>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="monthly_plan">
                    <div class="card first_mnth-details">
                        <p class="price">₹1699 per month</p>
                        <p>Save 37% On Trial Plan</p>
                        <p class="home-del">*Home delivered and billed monthly for the next 1 months</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-select"> Select</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-continue btn-block">Continue with 6 months plan
                         </button>
                     </div>
                </div>
```